# Time zones and time fields oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, timezone

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8884545/oracle-10g-time-zone-confusion) and the respective answers I made the next table:

[image]

Then I have the next questions:

1. What is the role of the Database time in this?
2. There is a way of obtain the time zone of the Database OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is a way of obtain the time zone of the Database OS?

Yes, you can do

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, 'TZR') FROM dual;
or
SELECT EXTRACT(TIMEZONE_REGION FROM SYSTIMESTAMP) FROM dual;
```

> What is the role of the Database time in this?

Actually this is not relevant in daily use, it is used only for `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE` data type columns and defines the storage format.

Take following analogy to understand `DBTIMEZONE` and `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE`: Whenever you have to work with time zones a common approach is to store **all** times in UTC and convert the time at application layer according to current user settings.

That is exactly how `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE` works but on SQL-Level. Only difference: Oracle does not store `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE` times fixed at **UTC** time but at **DBTIMEZONE** time. Hence you cannot change `DBTIMEZONE` on your database if the database contains a table with a `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE` column and the column contains data.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The weird part is that the first query result is "UNKNOWN" and the second one is "-3:00".

Comment: I assume `TZR` returns only a value if you you a fully qualified region name, e.g. `Europe/Zurich`. Usually DBTIMEZONE is set as UTC offset rather than time zone region, i.e. the offset is constant over the whole year and you don't apply any daylight saving.

Comment: The first query will give you exactly the same result as the second, and it does not require a "recognized" time zone, if instead of the format model `'TZR'` you use `'TZH:TZM'`.